# Converting a number to a date depending on another date

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I need to convert a number to a complete day, depending on another date. Since the action I'm analyzing begins one day after the variable "fechafin" and I'm predicting a day not a date, I need to transform it to a date, but if I say the 7th it has to be: 2014-07-07, and if I say the 3rd, has to be 2014-08-03.

Here's an example:

```
final_muestra1<-data.frame(prior_day1=c(1:17) )

fechafin=as.Date('2014-07-06')
```

So I define a function:

```
add.months= function(date,n) seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
```

and the first day of the action would be:

```
diapri<-as.numeric(format(fechafin+1, "%d"))
```

Then I need to compute the calendar date I'm predicting, so I used ifelse (since I have NA I add another ifelse)

```
final_muestra1$prior_day1_comp<-
  ifelse(!is.na(final_muestra1$prior_day1), 
            ifelse( final_muestra1$prior_day1>=diapri, 
                                 fechafin-diapri+final_muestra1$prior_day1, 
                                  add.months((fechafin-diapri+final_muestra1$prior_day1),1)),NA)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in seq.Date(date, by = paste(n, "months"), length = 2) :
>   'from' must be of length 1

I need to get the following table:

```
   prior_day1 prior_day1_comp
1           1  2014-08-01
2           2  2014-08-02
3           3  2014-08-03
4           4  2014-08-04
5           5  2014-08-05
6           6  2014-08-06
7           7  2014-07-07
8           8  2014-07-08
```

Comment: I did not fully understand what the desired behavior is (is it correct that 2014-07-07 is in the table twice?), but the error occurs because the `date` input to `add.months` is a vector of dates from 2014-06-30 to 2014-07-16 but has to be a single value since it is the start of `seq.Date`.

Comment: @Khl4v, no it was a mistake. The idea is super simple: keep the day but change the month depending on the day. If the day is bigger than diapri then keep the month if it's smaller then increase the month by 1. Thanks

Comment: @akrun, hi. some months have 30 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged your earlier code. Do check if this is fine:

```
library(chron)
final_muestra1<-data.frame(prior_day1=c(1:17) )
fechafin=as.Date('2014-07-06')
diapri<-as.numeric(format(fechafin, "%d"))  
add.months= function(date) seq(chron(as.numeric(date)), by = "months", length = 2)[2]

for (i in 1:nrow(final_muestra1)){a[i]<-ifelse(!is.na(final_muestra1$prior_day1[i]),ifelse( final_muestra1$prior_day1[i]>diapri, fechafin-diapri+final_muestra1$prior_day1[i], add.months(fechafin-diapri+final_muestra1$prior_day1[i])),NA)}

final_muestra1$prior_day1_comp<-a

final_muestra1
```

Comment: yep, but I didn't want to use another library

Answer (score 1):

I solve it another way (awful):
I created another date:

```
fecha_fin_cart=as.Date('2014-08-06')

diapri<-as.numeric(format(fechafin+1, "%d"))       



fechafin_pri<-as.Date(format(fechafin, "%Y-%m-01"))

fecha_fin_cart<-as.Date(format(fecha_fin_cart, "%Y-%m-01"))
```

Created another function:

```
gg<-function(d) {
  NAs <- is.na(d)
  august <- (!is.na(d) & d <= diapri)
  july <- (!is.na(d) & d > diapri)

  ret <- rep(as.Date("2014-01-01"), length(d))
  ret[august] <- (fecha_fin_cart) + (d[august]-1)
  ret[!august] <-(fechafin_pri) + (d[!august]-1)
  return(ret) 
}




final_muestra1$xx<-gg(final_muestra1$prior_day1)
```

And then:

```
final_muestra1
 prior_day1         xx
1           1 2014-08-01
2           2 2014-08-02
3           3 2014-08-03
4           4 2014-08-04
5           5 2014-08-05
6           6 2014-08-06
7           7 2014-07-07
8           8 2014-07-08
9           9 2014-07-09
10         10 2014-07-10
11         11 2014-07-11
12         12 2014-07-12
13         13 2014-07-13
14         14 2014-07-14
15         15 2014-07-15
16         16 2014-07-16
17         17 2014-07-17
18         NA       <NA>
```